# How to implement custom FlowLayout in a GEF editor?

Tags: java, swt, eclipse-gef, flowlayout, draw2d

I'm implementing a GEF editor and am facing the following problem.

There are two types of EditPart: 1) GraphEditPart, 2) NodeEditPart.
My editor extends `GraphicalEditor`, as I'm not needing a palette at all. I use `SimpleRootEditPart` for the `GraphicalViewer`.

`GraphEditPart` has a figure of type `Layer`, which is layed out with `FlowLayout`. Its model children are Nodes, which should be displayed according to `FlowLayout`, i.e., one after the other, with "line breaks" when a node figure (a `Label`) would move beyond the visible part of the `GraphicalViewer`. This would be the point where usually the horizontal scrollbar appears. To suppress the scrollbars, I have set `layer.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(getViewer().getControl().getSize()))`. This works well enough, so that when I resize the application window to a smaller size, the editor are gets smaller, and the node figures perform a quasi "line break" a la FlowLayout.

However, if I have a lot of nodes in the graph, I want to display the vertical scrollbar, because as it is now, the nodes just disappear below the bottom end of the screen.

So basically, the behaviour I want to achieve is like that of a text editor, which scrolls down if you just enter enough text (like the WYSIWYG text editor here on stackoverflow)...

I have tried to set the scrollbar visible by calling `((FigureCanvas) getViewer()).getControl.setVerticalScrollbarVisibility(FigureCanvas.AUTOMATIC))`, but to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that your are using a `SimpleRootEditPart`, which doesn't support scrolling. Try changing this to `ScalableRootEditPart` or even `ScalableFreeformRootEditPart` (that is what I am using). The call you are doing affects the control that contains the edit part, but since GEF manages it's own view, your call has no effect.

Comment: Isn't scrolling a feature of the `GraphicalViewer`'s `Control`? If I'm correct, the default `Control` for `ScrollingGraphicalViewer` (in turn the default viewer for all GEF editors in the type hierarchy downwards from `Graphical Editor` I think) is `FigureCanvas` (the API docs call it a "scrolling Canvas" anyway). Well, at least FigureCanvas provides static fields for scrollbar visibility.

@QueNuevo: vainolo is right in that your call cannot have any effect. Have you tried dynamically calculating the preferred size based on the `Bounds` of the children? Does this have an effect?

Comment: I did some digging in the code @s.d , and I think GEF has it's own scrolling mechanism that is not controlled by the Eclipse UI. But I'm a but rusty on eclipse lately so I may be wrong. Anyway, I always use the classes above and scrolling works.